# Auto click a link using casperJS evaluate

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, evaluate

I have the following HTML

```
    <div class="cart-rem-coupon">
        <span class="rem-icon" onclick="myVoucher.remove('2999','remove_voucher_
button');">&nbsp;</span><a onclick="myVoucher.remove('2999','remove_voucher_link
')" href="javascript:void(0)"><u>Remove Voucher</u></a>
    </div>
```

I want to autoclick such that

`document.getElementsByClassName("rem-icon")[0].click();` (this is inside the evaluate)

Am getting the following error :

`'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'document.getElementsByClassName
("rem-icon")[0].click()')`

Any rason where am i doing wrong??

Comment: Could you post some more code? I was able to run this without any issues.

Comment: try debugging it with `__utils__.echo()`